# Where are the gradient queues and token queue created in Tensorflow between-graph sync training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have been working on Tensorflow between-graph synchronous training application. Sync training is achieved by class SyncReplicasOptimizerV2.  From the document of [class SyncReplicasOptimizerV2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py#L39), I understand a set of gradient queues and a token queue are created for synchronizing.

I was wondering

1. where are these queues located, the chief worker task or ps tasks?
   If gradients queues are in chief worker, and as far as I know the chief worker task also has to handle checkpoints, initialization, summary...
2. Is this single chief worker task prone to be performance bottleneck?
3. is there any network communication between different worker tasks (except chief), if yes what's the network communication exists for?

PS: all my questions are in the scenario of conducting between-graph replicated training with each task being in a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the new implementation of synchronous training, in [`tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizerV2`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d9c173fc7adf9443d58310dd08a84b9eb89d4c8f/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py#L39), does not actually use a set of queues for the variables. It uses a more efficient stateful object called a "conditional accumulator", which avoids storing the unaggregated partial gradients in memory, and improves the behavior in some corner cases with stale gradients.

1. The conditional accumulator for each variable is located on the same device as that variable, which is usually on a PS task ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d9c173fc7adf9443d58310dd08a84b9eb89d4c8f/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py#L281)); thus the many conditional accumulators will be sharded according to the same policy used for sharing the variables. The token queue for synchronization, on which the workers block before starting the next step, is created on the same device as the global step variable, which is also usually a single PS task ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d9c173fc7adf9443d58310dd08a84b9eb89d4c8f/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py#L310)).
2. Typically, the work that the chief worker task has to do to coordinate synchronous training is small. No additional data flows through the chief worker (in a typical setup, using e.g. [`tf.traing.replica_device_setter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#replica_device_setter) to assign devices to the variables) when performing synchronous training.
3. Synchronous training doesn't create any additional between-worker network traffic. Of course, you can choose to place different parts of your model on different workers for model-parallel training, and in that case TensorFlow will add the appropriate communication. However, the image models (such as Inception) for which we commonly use synchronous training do not require model parallelism, and run more efficiently on a single GPU.